# Change keyboard layout with hotkey?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to avoid using my right hand due to pain recently and have been typing with one hand on the keyboard.

Is there a way to have a hot key toggle (say caps lock) which when pressed and held down alters the keyboard layout (flipping the left hand side keys with the right for example).

Answer (score 3):

You can switch between installed keyboard layouts with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>
or in Windows 10 with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

You can create your own keyboard layout with the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339).

You have to manually create this custom layout, and use the above mentioned combinations to switch between the two layouts.

Comment: yeah i'm aware of that feature, but I'm looking for something I can use as part of regular typing rather than a hard toggle.

Comment: I know, that RAZER has this feature where you can toggle vith a pre determined key to give every key another functionality, you could add a macro on every key to "press" another key

Comment: @meds , there is no difference between 'hard toggle' and 'part of regular typing' - only your perception of it.

Comment: @Aganju Aside from the fact alt+shift is one button too many for my purposes and changes your keyboard layout permanently until you press it again.

Comment: you can define the switch key(s) yourself, Alt+Shift is only the default. I got used to continuously switch back and forth while typing.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add on to Nordlys Jeger awnser

I've created a little script so that when you press the Capslock key it will send <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

You will need to install [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/download/) its great for remapping keys.
Once AHK is installed open notepad and enter the code below and save it as a .ahk file and run it.

```
CapsLock::
    Send #{Space}
    Return
```

CapsLock:: will excute the code below when Capslock is pressed

Send #{Space} will press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Now you just have to press Caplocks to change between the keyboards of your choosing.

If you would like to know more about what keys you can use you can read more about it [Here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm) so you can change it to an F-key if you like :)